# Are sub-selects in a where-clauses executed multiple times or just once?

Tags: mysql

I have a separate table (with no PK, only one row) to store the row count of a certain result. Now, this count is used in a query, like this (just an example):

```
SELECT * FROM `car`
WHERE `car`.`featured` = 1
AND ( SELECT `count` FROM `carfeaturedcounter` ) > 5;
```

Will `SELECT count FROM carfeaturedcounter` be executed multiple times (once for every row), or only once per query?

Comment: Only once. Subqueries are inefficient but not that inefficient.

Comment: @StormoPL yeah, I figured that it won't be super-efficient, but I hope more efficient than using a COUNT() each time - especially later when there are lots of entries :)

Comment: I don't know your db structure but I guess correct approach to this kind of subject would be through HAVING option while you join car_features to car, GROUP BY car_id and COUNT car_features. Having separate table just for counter is a bit unorthodox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the version of MySQL.  You might as well move the condition to the `from` clause, where it will only be executed once:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM car c.CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT `count` FROM carfeaturedcounter) x
WHERE c.featured = 1 AND x.`count` > 5;
```